What If statement can be written for if AudioGraph has stopped?
What is trying to be achieved is to create an If statement that if the AudioGraph, graph2, has been stopped, to change the button, playButton's, content into Play Recorded File. But this has not been possible to achieve as of yet.
When trying to create an If statement such as:
if (graph2 == Stopped)
{
    playButton.Content = "Play Recorded File";
}

The error is:

The name 'Stopped' does not exist in the current context

Since "'Stopped' does not exist in the current context", what term or If statement would cause what is trying to be achieved?

That error means that the name doesn't exist in the current context. Do you intend that it represent a local variable or a class field or property. You don't show us where you declared (or didn't declare) it, so there's not much else we can say

@Flydog57 I have updated my question to hopefully offer some clarity as to what in particular I was asking about.

You would write your code to save the audio graph state, for example ToggleRecordStop.

An AudioGraph appears to be a network (i.e., a graph) of audio processing nodes through which audio processing happens. You can call Start() on the graph to tell the nodes to start processing and Stop() to tell them to stop. But, the graph as a whole does not seem to be aware of any started/stopped state. I believe this level of state awareness is something you will need to monitor yourself. Sorry, that's as much as I can guess at after a short time browsing the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiograph?view=winrt-26100.  Try some samples for help

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT Can you elaborate further as to which portion of ToggleRecordStop you're referring to? Thanks.

@Flydog57 has explained this. For ToggleRecordStop, it uses the button content to monitor the audio graph state and processing follows that.
